# WCF Client Timeouts

Tags: .net, silverlight, wcf

I have Silverlight application which connects to a WCF service.

If i open the open connection at the start of the application and then say give it 10 minutes or so before the client comes to call a method it will time out.

I understand that it is easy to change the timeout time in the web.config.

However what I’m looking for it for the WCF service to remain active to say 5 minutes after the soap client has been closed.
I though about maybe running a background thread in Silverlight which calls a WCF method which doesn’t do anything but this feels rather hacky.

Is there more of a professional way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: First: To my understanding WCF uses HTTP but not SOAP, this is one of the reasons why WCF Services are faster than XML Web Services... :)

Comment: Second: Why would you like to keep the service layer running even if nobody needs it? I think you should consider this deeply and eventually improve the overall design on this aspect.

Comment: for example if you have a bussniess application and they walk away for a metting for 24 hours i want it still to be active when they come back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change InstanceContextMode to signleton and start the service in the service constructor. Using signleton  mode means that your session never expires.

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single)]
```

Another solution is changing the InstanceContextMode  to PerSession and set the InactivityTimeout to something like 1 hour.

```
<bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="WSHttpBinding" >
        <reliableSession inactivityTimeout="01:00:00" enabled="true" />
      </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
```

UPDATE(After reading your comment): You can also set the inactivityTimeout="infinite".